# Why does declaring an object inside a loop not erase object data?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I found a function to extract data from a 3d array, and save it to an object. This is the code:

```
function objectifyData(arr) {
  return arr.map(a => {
    var obj = {};
    a.map(b => {
      obj[b[0]] = b[1];
    });
    return obj;
  })
}
```

My question is: given that the first `.map` runs twice, why is obj not emptied when it is declared (`var obj = {}`) on the second loop?

Comment: Can you attach the  running code snippet of what you are asking?

Comment: Can you provide some minimal sample input, actual output and expected output?

Comment: Each iteration of the first loop creates a new object, it doesn't modify the `obj` object from the previous iteration.

Comment: Each iteration is a new variable scope, so there's no relationship between the `obj` variables in each loop. But even if it were the same scope, assigning to a variable doesn't modify the previous contents of the variable.